# "Too much of an ask after all" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've got answer from support team regarding cirrylic issue in the software. They have written me:

> It might be we've had a regression so we'll have the devs take a peek
>   and see if we can get this sorted. I don't think using your native
>   language is too much of an ask after all ;-)

What does phrase "*too much of an ask after all*" mean?

I suspect, that meaning is something like this:

> This problem shouldn't be a big issue for us after all.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a request that would not be too difficult to accommodate.  You are correct in your understanding.

P.S. "ask" is really a verb, but is often used, in job-related jargon, as a noun —when the job frequently involves having to make or act upon requests.

Comment: I had to read it 3 times, but I'm not sure I quite agree with your interpretation. I'm reading it as "asking for a feature that should [& used to] work correctly in your own language is not too much to ask for" Subtle but significant difference, I think. More the 'reasonableness of the request' than the 'difficulty of making the fix'.

Comment: @Tetsujin:  you may be right about the nuance, though I have my doubts that a person responding to a request for a feature would be commenting upon the *reasonableness* of a request; they would focus instead on the *feasibility* of adding the feature and/or on the cost-benefit of devoting programming resources to a feature that might not be widely desired.

Comment: It feels like a way to be endearing or chummy to me, owning up to a feature that had a regression, missed at beta-testing, rather than emphasising the company's potential cost/effort to fix it. [I wouldn't bet the farm on my interpretation, it's just how it felt when I read it ;)

Comment: Interesting ambiguity @Tetsujin. My answer would have been the same as TRomano's, but I do see your point. And the mention of "your native language" strengthens that idea of it perhaps being a comment on the request's reasonableness as opposed to ease of fix. Overall, I'd still probably side with TRomano, but I'd really like to see more context to decide. Very nice example overall folks :-)

Comment: Two years on from my original comment; I still think it could be paraphrased as "I don't think asking us to put back the language pack we forgot to include in our recent version is an unreasonable request".

Comment: I don't know the particulars of the situation, but if it is indeed a very minor request, to say that it is "not too much of an ask" would be a variety of *litotes*.  "not too much of an ask" = "a very small request".  The difficulty in interpreting it more pointedly (as endearing/chummy) is that we don't know the full context. For whatever reason, it is not too "big" or too "great" a request. If you want to substitute "not unreasonable" for "not too big", that's not unreasonable.